# Create SubFolder within main folder using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have my macro to separate and create new workbooks for unique values by email address and add the unique value workbooks to a folder.

What I am now trying to do is add to this so that it will do the same thing with a slight twist. I need a folder to be created by a column containing an Organization name (There are about 100 different organizations) and then have it create new workbooks based off of unique values by email address (the same thing it currently does.) I just can't figure out how to add that extra folder of Organization name and still run as it does.

Most of the code I am using I found online, I made a couple slight modifications for my personal use.

```
Sub Copy_To_Workbooks()
    Dim My_Range As Range
    Dim FieldNum As Long
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim ViewMode As Long
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim foldername As String
    Dim Lrow As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim CCount As Long
    Dim WSNew As Worksheet
    Dim ErrNum As Long

    Set My_Range = Range("A1:Q" & LastRow(ActiveSheet))
    My_Range.Parent.Select

    If ActiveWorkbook.ProtectStructure = True Or _
       My_Range.Parent.ProtectContents = True Then
        MsgBox "Sorry, not working when the workbook or worksheet is protected", _
               vbOKOnly, "Copy to new workbook"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    FieldNum = 4

    'Turn off AutoFilter
    My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

    'Set the file extension/format
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        'You use Excel 97-2003
        FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
    Else
        'You use Excel 2007-2013
        If ActiveWorkbook.FileFormat = 56 Then
            FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
        Else
            FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
        End If
    End If

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

    'Delete the sheet RDBLogSheet if it exists
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("RDBLogSheet").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Add worksheet to copy/Paste the unique list
    Set ws2 = Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
    ws2.Name = "RDBLogSheet"

    'Fill in the path\folder where you want the new folder with the files
    MyPath = “U:\Updates”


    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    End If


    foldername = MyPath & Format("Helper Cases") & "\"
    MkDir foldername

    With ws2
        'first we copy the Unique data from the filter field to ws2
        My_Range.Columns(FieldNum).AdvancedFilter _
                Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
                CopyToRange:=.Range("A3"), Unique:=True

        'loop through the unique list in ws2 and filter/copy to a new sheet
        Lrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For Each cell In .Range("A4:A" & Lrow)

            'Filter the range
            My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum, Criteria1:="=" & _
             Replace(Replace(Replace(cell.Value, "~", "~~"), "*", "~*"), "?", "~?")

            'Check if there are no more then 8192 areas(limit of areas)
            CCount = 0
            On Error Resume Next
            CCount = My_Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) _
                     .Areas(1).Cells.Count
            On Error GoTo 0
            If CCount = 0 Then
                MsgBox "There are more than 8192 areas for the value : " & cell.Value _
                     & vbNewLine & "It is not possible to copy the visible data." _
                     & vbNewLine & "Tip: Sort your data before you use this macro.", _
                       vbOKOnly, "Split in worksheets"
            Else
                'Add new workbook with one sheet
                Set WSNew = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)

                'Copy/paste the visible data to the new workbook
                My_Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
                With WSNew.Range("A1")
                    ' Paste:=8 will copy the columnwidth in Excel 2000 and higher
                    ' Remove this line if you use Excel 97
                    .PasteSpecial Paste:=8
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                    .Select
                End With

                'Save the file in the new folder and close it
                On Error Resume Next
                WSNew.Parent.SaveAs foldername & _
                                    cell.Value & FileExtStr, FileFormatNum
                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    ErrNum = ErrNum + 1

                    WSNew.Parent.SaveAs foldername & _
                     "Error_" & Format(ErrNum, "0000") & FileExtStr, FileFormatNum

                    .Cells(cell.Row, "B").Formula = "=Hyperlink(""" & foldername & _
                      "Error_" & Format(ErrNum, "0000") & FileExtStr & """)"

                    .Cells(cell.Row, "A").Interior.Color = vbRed
                Else
                    .Cells(cell.Row, "B").Formula = _
                    "=Hyperlink(""" & foldername & cell.Value & FileExtStr & """)"
                End If

                WSNew.Parent.Close False
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If

            'Show all the data in the range
            My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum

        Next cell
        .Cells(1, "A").Value = "Red cell: can't use the Unique name as file name"
        .Cells(1, "B").Value = "Created Files (Click on the link to open a file)"
        .Cells(3, "A").Value = "Unique Values"
        .Cells(3, "B").Value = "Full Path and File name"
        .Cells(3, "A").Font.Bold = True
        .Cells(3, "B").Font.Bold = True
        .Columns("A:B").AutoFit

    End With

    'Turn off AutoFilter
    My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

    If ErrNum > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Rename every WorkSheet name that start with ""Error_"" manually" _
             & vbNewLine & "There are characters in the name that are not allowed" _
             & vbNewLine & "in a sheet name or the worksheet already exist."
    End If

    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
    My_Range.Parent.Select
    ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
    ws2.Select
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With

End Sub


Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: You have the `MkDir` line in your code.  You can see how `foldername` is defined to be a full path with an ending "\".  Now just create a loop through your organization name column and perform the `MkDir` operation using references to the organization name cells via the loop.

Comment: @tigeravatar - I'm having trouble creating and executing a second loop as suggested.

Comment: Edit your question to be limited to only the relevant portion (making subfolders) and leave the rest of the code out.  Show what you've tried so far and any errors you are getting.

Comment: I've added the following to the loop section:
 foldername = MyPath & "Organizations\" & WSNew.Range("D2") & \"
          If foldername <> "ARH Regional Medical Center" Then
: MkDir foldername
    End If
       foldername = MyPath & "Organizations\" & WSNew.Range("G2") & "\"

And I have tried it without the "If statement and just shows the two foldername parts above When I run or Step-Through I get a Run-time error '75' Path/File access error message. I think already notices that the named organization folder already exists and can't add new workbook for new person to the same folder.

Comment: This works here.   foldername = MyPath & "Organizations\" & WSNew.Range("D2") & "\"
If Dir(foldername, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir foldername